# Are there requirements to build certain public works?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Is there any kind of requirement for public works to be suggested by villagers? Something like X days into the game? Certain town rate? 2nd floor of museum?

I'm currently working on getting the 2nd floor of museum, and I've tried all the tricks people suggest over the internet, even the ones shown in videos working but none have worked for me yet. I was kind of wondering if it was because my town right now has only 8 villagers (one of them moved out) or because my villagers aren't happy enough with the town or because I haven't built the 2nd floor of the museum or what. I've been playing over one month now, and I can't get any requests. I need help.

Here is a list of what I've built so far:

- First bridge (doesn't count)
- Dream suite
- 2 street lights
- camping site
- fountain (the first one you get)
- water well
- yellow bench (it was on the list already)

So I hope someone can help me out with this...

Comment: What are some examples of tricks people have suggested over the internet? If it's the one that involves going swimming for a while and coming back, I find that that one works best if you empty your pockets of all items and bells (no chance for a villager to want to buy/sell things when they "!" at you). There's still a lot of waiting/luck involved though, but not nearly as much. I don't know of any prerequisites though.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement is that they give it to you (random) and, for some projects, that the villager is of the right personality type. [The AC Wikia has the list of projects and which villagers request them](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Public_Works_Projects).

Comment: I have some of the tipes that request things I want but they aren't requesting at all

Comment: @AlonsoReche It's fairly rare, I get them maybe once a week or less. When it happens they always do the thing where they see you, get excited then run up to you with something to say. Talking to them normally will never give you a project.

Comment: I know all of that, I've been looking up a lot of videos and info on pages that tell how to get them and show people getting them using those methods but it didn't work for me so i was wondering if there was any requisite for them =(

Answer (score 0):

I just finished building the 2nd floor of the museum and as soon as I was done with the celebration 2 villagers offered me public works...this hadn't happened before at all so I'm starting to think you either need to have the 2nd floor of museum or have spent certain amount of money into public works...